# How To Tell SendMail To Explicitly NOT Try TLS For A Domain

Tags: linux, email, centos, sendmail, tls

CentOS 5.x | Sendmail

Hi Guys,

I have sendmail setup to perform opportunistic TLS but would like to never use TLS when sending to a specific domain.  Is there an entry I can add to /etc/mail/access to tell the server not to use it (regardless of whether or not the receiving MTA advertises support)?

M

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why?

Comment: One reason: There exists broekn/misconfigured mail servers (for instance, iqc3.math.uwaterloo.ca) that will reject mail coming in on the SMTPS port. (different MikeyB, BTW)

Comment: TLS doesn't operate on the SMTPS (SSL) port, but I suppose it would be possible to configure a server such that encrypted sessions need to authenticate; which yours is obviously not looking to do. Good call on the "misconfigured server".

Comment: Rigid change management structure. =)

Comment: Thinkoed there - still rather annoyed at their misconfiguration :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the /etc/mail/access file, add the line:

```
Try_TLS:broken.server   NO
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed.  Good name btw ;-)

Comment: Go Team Mike B! :D